# Inserting customUI into excel document

Tags: xml

Basically I used XML marker to add a custom ui into a workbook about 18 months ago. It comprises of this:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
 <backstage> 
        <button idMso="ApplicationOptionsDialog" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
        <button idMso="FileSaveAs" visible="false"/>
        <tab idMso="TabShare" visible="false"/>
 </backstage>
</customUI>
```

I cannot for the life of me remember how I did it, I need to add this to a new workbook, I just can't remember how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Office Custom UI Editor" from openxmldeveloper.org, and follow the steps mentioned as in http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_ribbon_main.html
Hope this would help you.